# $M$ is open in $Y$ and $M$ is open in $Z$ then $M$ is open in $X$

Tags: general-topology

Is it true?

$X= Y \cup Z$, $M$ is a subset of $Y \cap Z$. Suppose that $M$ is open in $Y$ and $M$ is open in $Z$ then  $M$ is open in $X$.

Comment: For reference, this is an problem from Bourbaki.

Comment: In your problem, is $M$ supposed to *equal* $Y \cap Z$, or be a *subset* of $Y \cap Z$? Your statement seems to say that that $M = Y \cap Z$, but your comment on an answer suggests it's any subset.

Comment: It is a subset.

Answer (score 2):

If $A ⊆ Y ∩ Z$ is not open in $X$, then there is some $x ∈ A$ such that $x ∈ \overline{X \setminus A} = \overline{Y \setminus A} ∪ \overline{Z \setminus A}$.

Comment: You are right, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $M\subset Y\cap Z$, and $M$ is an open subset of $Y$ and $Z$ with their subspace topologies inherited from $X$. Then there exists an open $U\subset X$ such that $M= U\cap Y$, and there exists an open $V\subset X$ such that $M= V\cap Z$. But then as $M$ is a subset of both $U$ and $V$, $M$ must be a subset of their intersection $U\cap V$ which is an open subset of $X$.

So, $M = (U\cap V)\cap Y$ and $M = (U\cap V) \cap Z$, But note that $U\cap V$ is a subset of both $Y$ and $Z$, and so $$(U\cap V)\cap Y = (U\cap V)\cap Z = U\cap V.$$ Hence $M=U\cap V$ which is open.